# Need help understanding the motivation for parametric statistical models

Tags: statistics

First, let me present the definition of a statistical model and a parametric statistical model.

**Definition**: A statistical model consists of a set of measures $\mathcal{P}$ on a measurable space $(\mathcal{X},\mathbb{E})$.

**Definition**: A statistical model is said to be parametric if there exists some surjective function $v:\Theta\to\mathcal{P}$, where $\Theta\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{k}$ is called the parameter space. The parameterised model is then given by $\mathcal{P}=\{v(\theta)\mid \theta\in\Theta\}$.

In regards to the first definition, is it not true to say that the goal in statistics is to infer which one of the measures in $\mathcal{P}$ is the true measure of some underlying experiment? And likewise, in regards to the second definition, we would like to infer which of the parameters in $\Theta$ is the true parameter of some underlying experiment, right?

This made me wonder what the motivation for parametric models is; I mean why do we want to infer a parameter instead of a measure?

**Additional question**: How would one extend the two definitions such that they include random variables?

I hope my questions are somewhat clear, but let me know if they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

> This made me wonder what the motivation for parametric models is; I mean why do we want to infer a parameter instead of a measure?

> Additional question: How would one extend the two definitions such that they include random variables?

Let me start from your additional question

Assuming that the Probability Measures are dominated by a $\sigma\text{-finite}$ measure, they could be descrtipted by the Density Function $p(z|\theta)$ with respect to this measure.

As a consequence, if A is any events belonging to the $\sigma\text{-Algebra}$ $\mathcal{F}$ we will have

$$\mathbb{P}(A|\theta)=\int_{A}p(z|\theta)d \mu(x)$$

$\theta \in \Theta$

In this situation the Statistical Model can be represented in a simplyfied form:

$$\Big(Z,p(z|\theta),\theta \in \Theta\Big)$$

In other words, for every choice of $\theta \in \Theta$ se select a density function that regulate the *"random mechanism"* on the experiment data.

Thus we are in front of a *"double uncertainty"*

1. around the value of $\theta \in \Theta$
2. around the experiment data regulated by the density function $p(z|\theta)$ once that $\theta \in \Theta$ is chosen

---

When $\Theta$ is a subset of an Euclidean Space, the Statistical model is said Parametric, elsewhere it is said Non-Parametric

---

**Why using a parametric model rather than a Non-Parametric one?**

This depends on the inference problem you are facing. There are different inference tools that can be applied in the two kind of model, and different information you have before chosing the appropriate tool to solve the problem...

**Example 1**

Suppose we have a urn with black and white balls but we do not know the % of White balls. to estimate this % we draw (with replacing) $$n$ draws setting

$X=1$ if the drawn ball is W; $\rightarrow\mathbb{P}[X=1]=\theta$

$X=0$ if the drawn ball is B; $\rightarrow\mathbb{P}[X=0]=1-\theta$

In this situation

$$p(x|\theta)=\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}$$

$x=0;1$ and $0\leq\theta\leq 1$

Thus the model is a Parametric one and there is no need to introduce a non parametric one..

The Statistical Model is this

$$\Bigg(\mathcal{X}^{(n)};\theta^{\Sigma_i x_i}(1-\theta)^{n-\Sigma_i x_i};\theta \in [0;1]\Bigg)$$

Here

a) $\mathcal{X}^{(n)}$ is the set of all possible $n\text{-tuples}$ $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ where every element can take the values $\{0;1\}$

b) the function $\theta^{\Sigma_i x_i}(1-\theta)^{n-\Sigma_i x_i}$ assigns the probability to any possible $n\text{-tuple}$ given that $\theta$ is known

**Example 2**

Let's consider the class $\mathcal{F}$ of all the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) on $\mathcal{R}$.

If we consider the Statistical Model, as usual using a Sampling with repetition from the Base Model we have

$$\Bigg(\mathcal{R}^n; \prod_{i=1}^{n}F_{X_i}(x_i);F \in \mathcal{F}\Bigg)$$

---

Concluding, we can say that the difference between Parametric and Non-parametric Models is essentially based on the structure of the CDF's included in $\mathcal{F}$.
If they are **all and only** the ones derived by a certain analytical law with an unknown parameter (that can be also a vector) thus the model is parametric.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know George Box' famous quote: "All models are wrong, but some are useful."? In this light, I would say that the goal of statistics is not necessarily to find the true underlying model, i.e. the true data generating process, but to find an approximation that is useful in some way. This could be to get a better understanding about the underlying data generating process, but also to make good predictions for future data. These two tasks are fundamentally different: for either task you would learn a different model.

There is always a trade-off between choosing a simple model, and a model that fits the data well. If the model is too complex, e.g. it contains too many parameters, it can fit the data too well: it overfits, i.e. it not only learns the signal, but also the noise. If the model is too simple, it underfits, it doesn't learn the signal well enough. I also would say that there is no dichotomy between measures and parametric models, a statistical model could for example be a set of Gaussian distributions with a real mean and positive variance, this is a parametric model.